# Python operator overloading query

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Assume that we define `x = C(['0'])` where the class C is defined by

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,los):
        self.los = los

    def __lt__(self,right):
        if type(right) is C:
            return self.los < right.los
        elif type(right) is int:
            return self.los < [d for d in str(right)]
        else:
            raise TypeError('unorderable types: C() < '+type_as_str(right)+'()')

x = C(['0'])
print(12<x)
```

When the above code is executed it returns 'False'. 
If my understanding is well, then for `12<x`, it will be `12.__lt__(x)`, which is nothing but `type(12).__lt__(12, x)` or `int.__lt__(12, x)`. So, it will try to use the `__lt__` method in standard `int` class. But it should throw error message as this method doesn't understand the comparison of `int` with class object. So, this exception will be managed internally and then it should call `x.__lt__(12)` or `type(x).__lt__(x, 12)`. It means that finally it should use the `__lt__` method defined inside class C.

But it seems that this class is never invoked as I tried to put some prints in this `__lt__` method of class `C` and `print(12<x)` always returns `False`.

Can somebody explain this in detail please?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that `int.__lt__(12, x)` won't work; that method returns the `NotImplemented` singleton in that case:

```
>>> int.__lt__(12, x)
NotImplemented
```

However, Python then calls `type(x).__gt__()`, **not `__lt__`,** as the inverse:

```
>>> class Demo:
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         print('__lt__ called')
...         return NotImplemented
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         print('__gt__ called')
...         return NotImplemented
...
>>> 12 < Demo()
__gt__ called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < Demo()
```

That's because you can still determine if 12 is smaller than the other object by asking the other object if 12 is bigger than it. If you asked for the inverse (`12 > x`) *then* your `C.__lt__()` is called:

```
>>> 12 > Demo()
__lt__ called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > Demo()
```

Note that *Python* raises the `TypeError` exception, because `Demo.__gt__()` and `Demo.__lt__()` both returned `NotImplemented` *too*. You don't have to raise the exception yourself.